How is the name "Took" pronounced?
After hearing someone pronounce "Took" (as in "Fool Of A...") the same as the English word "took", I wondered to myself: Have I been pronouncing it wrong this whole time? Did the movies pronounce it wrong? So I checked the Appendices and as far as I can tell, Tolkien is pretty unclear about the pronunciation of Hobbit names, other than to say:

The Westron or Common Speech has been entirely translated into English equivalents. All Hobbit names and special words are intended to be pronounced accordingly: for example, Bolger has g as in bulge, and mathom rhymes with fathom.

So which is it? Did Tolkien ever clarify?

Rhymes with "book" (/tʊk/)
Rhymes with "duke" (/tuːk/)


Please note that "duke" is pronounced rather differently by different people: one with the sound from "you", one with the sound from "ook". I presume you mean the latter? (asking as someone who hasn't got the phonetic alphabet memorised)

For the record, I’ve always heard Ian McKellen’s/Gandalf’s pronunciation (as in “Fool of a Took!”) as /tʊk/, not /tuːk/.

Where I'm from, took (and book and look) can have a long vowel as in snooker.  It's actually closer to the pronunciation of duke.

BWFC, I may be misunderstanding you comment. Are you saying look is pronounce like Luke?

@David They mean the vowel from GOOSE /uː/, not "you" /juː/ nor FOOT /ʊ/.

@BWFC "snooker" can be pronounced with a short vowel, /snʊkər/, in North America as well as Wales I believe. GOOSE is the more standard way of referring to that vowel, /u:/.

@wjandrea, fair enough, it was the best example I could think of at the time.

@CGCampbell, that's right.  In the North of England, 'look, sky walker' could be an instruction to look up.

In French the name is translated to « Touque » /tʊk/ and I think it's beautiful

The English comedian and broadcaster Barry Took pronounced his name /tʊk/

It's pronounced /tuːk/:

In the case of persons, however, Hobbit-names in the Shire and in Bree were for those days peculiar, notably in the habit that had grown up, some centuries before this time, of having inherited names for families. Most of these surnames had obvious meanings in the current language, being derived from jesting nicknames, or from place-names, or (especially in Bree) from the names of plants and trees. Translation of these presented little difficulty; but there remained one or two older names of forgotten meaning, and these I have been content to anglicize in spelling: as Took for Tûk, or Boffin for Bophîn.
LotR, Appendix F "The Languages and Peoples of the Third Age", II "On Translation"

Where the caret on the "u" in this case indicates a long vowel:

Long vowels are usually marked with the 'acute accent', as in some varieties of Fëanorian script. In Sindarin long vowels in stressed monosyllables are marked with the circumflex, since they tended in such cases to be specially prolonged; so in dûn compared with Dúnadan.
LotR, Appendix E "Writing and Spelling", I "Pronunciation of Words and Names", Vowels


Aha, I hadn't checked Appendix F. Thanks!

These are from the Appendices to The Lord of the Rings; they should be part of any 3-volume set or omnibus.

Note that in some English accents the vowels in  "book"  and "boot" are very similar.

I’m not sure these quotes are really definitive. Yes, the Westron form definitely has a long vowel /tuːk/, but that doesn’t necessarily mean the English translation does. As mentioned in the quote in the question, Hobbit names are “entirely translated into English equivalents” and “intended to be pronounced accordingly”. Bophîn has a long vowel in the second syllable, but I’ve never seen anyone argue that Boffin should be pronounced /ˈbɒfiːn/ (Boffeen), rather than as the existing English word boffin. A similar argument could be made for took.

@JanusBahsJacquet Of course I don't know, but I expect if Tolkien had intended a short vowel he would have chosen the unambiguous "Tuck". For the long vowel, there's no equally good alternative: British readers would expect "Tuke" to be pronounced /tju:k/.

@EspeciallyLime Tuck would be /tʌk/ rather than /tʊk/; different vowel. Inasmuch as spelling pronunciation is based on existing English words, took is quite unambiguously /tʊk/ (past tense of take). But it is true that there is no good, unambiguous alternative for /tuːk/ that would fit. Touque would be fairly unambiguous, but it looks French, which Tolkien specifically avoided for Westron words (being closer to Sindarin in terms of prestige and influence).

@JanusBahsJacquet Most accents from north and central England (which includes the region where Tolkien spent most of his childhood) lack the foot-strut split, and pronounce -uck as ʊk.  There are also some northern accents where -uck is ʊk and -ook is u:k. I'm now starting to wonder about my orang-utan pronunciation :)

@EspeciallyLime: Tolkien’s readings of LoTR clearly show he does have the foot-strut split, as for instance in asunder at 00:36 here with .ʌ/, as part of the RP one would expect from an establishment intellectual of his generation.  So tuck for him would certainly have represented /tʌk/ not /tʊk/.  (Edit: and took can also be heard at 1:35 in that video as /tʊk/ “and the hosts of Mordor wailed, and the terror overtook them”.)

@Plutor Always check Appendix F :-)

@PLL If you can find a recording of Tolkien actually reading a second that contains Pippin’s surname, that would make an excellent, irrefutable answer!

In Sindarin long vowels are marked <-- but Tûk is Westron, so...

@EspeciallyLime I know someone from Manchester with surname Tuke, and he pronounces it like you say.

This answer seems to claim that 1. Tolkien intended the pronunciation /tuːk/ for this name; 2. accordingly he "anglicized" "Tûk" as "Took" and left it at that. Extraordinary, isn't it?  Since many readers will simply read "Took" as /tʊk/.

@anemone That's... honestly not that surprising. Consider the multiple real-world schemes used to romanize Japanese, for example.

@KarlKnechtel Most comments under this answer take up the issue whether there might be an ambiguity in the pronunciation of "Took" after all, even though the answer opens with "It's pronounced /tuːk/:" Whether or not you may find it "surprising", my comment follows that line, articulated earlier by Janus. As I said above, I am inclined to think that, had Tolkien had an unambiguous intent as to pronunciation, namely  /tuːk/:, he would have opted for a matching spelling or, were it not available, left a guide.
